# Ошибка в скрипте Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d, разработка-игр

К обьекту прикрепил данный скрипт, цель: автоматическое смещени е обьекта по оси Y, в итоге ничего не срабатывает. В чем проблема?

```
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using UnityEngine;

 public class move : MonoBehaviour {
    void Start () {
        transform.position.y += 1;
    }

    void Update () {
        transform.position.y += 1;  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вам выдаёт вполне очевидную ошибку - невозможно изменить значение, т.к. оно не является переменной.
`transform.position` - возвращает вам `Vector3`.

`Vector3` в Unity является значимым типом, который нельзя изменять. Другими словами, вы можете создать вектор с какими-то значениями, например `new Vector3(1, 1, 1)`, но после этого не сможете изменить в нём эти значения. Это связано с оптимизацией производительности и исключения некоторых частых ошибок.

Другими словами, в `transform.position` вам нужно назначать новый вектор, который будет равен вектору текущего положения + вектор смещения.

```
transform.position = transform.position + new Vector(0,1,0);
```

Перегруженный оператор += позволит вам сократить выражение. Он сам возьмёт текущее значение, прибавит к нему ваш вектор и потом назначит обратно.

```
transform.position += new Vector(0,1,0);
```